# How to disallow making changes or deleting file at main destination

Tags: windows, networking

Is there any way to prevent making changes/deleting files on partition or folder?

I need a solution, to allow workers to download/copy the file into their local folder but to disallow making any changes or deleting the file at the main destination.

A system which we using is Windows, and we currently don't use Windows Server.

Any ideas?

Best regards.
AK.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the permissions on the folder they are downloading from to allow read but not write or modify for the user/pass they are using to access the share. Then they can copy the file to their local machine all they want but can't modify anything on the share folder.

Comment: It will don't work, becouse user which is using computer which I named as "main destination" should cannot making any changes or deleting files too. When I will use this solution, user could easy brokeing my limitations by changing in proporties of file/folder permissions tab. The best solution which I found, is use "Easy File Locker" software (it's freeware software) where you could define locations which will be protected before making changes, and changing perrmissions of blocked file doesnt working. When you want disable protection, you must just enter password and switch off application.

Answer (score -1):

The solution to this problem is software called "Easy File Locker" (freeware software) which one allows add localization which will be blocked from making any changes. To disable protection by application you must enter password and switch off software.

Best regards.
AK.